# How can my client grant me access to his Azure website and database?

Tags: azure

I need to publish a new web app to my client's Azure website. How can he give me access, without giving me his own credentials to log in? I know this is somehow possible, as I have had access to other Azure accounts before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't explain it to you, just read [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/), it should be enough

well basically

1. Select your resource group
2. View access page and click plus button
3. Select role
4. Select/add user